# migrating storage to a different controller

Tags: vmware-esx, vmware-vsphere

I've just purcheased a couple of adaptec controller (2405/5405) for my ESXi 4.0 U1 servers. Currently ESXi and a couple of VMs are hosted on single sata boot disk connected to a nvidia on board non-RAID controller.

I know that it's possible to migrate from single disk to RAID 1 with adaptec and I'm pleased with that, but I'm not sure if ESXi has already the right drivers installed/loaded for this controller.

Is there any way I can check this? Is ESXi clever enough to recognize the new hardware and load the right module?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Both are on the HCL and will support single disks or RAID arrays.